# flashfirebug As3 console timer or setInterval not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, firebug

i have tried to use a timer in the as3 console from FlashFirebug addon but it doesn't work (have tried several combinations). The timer code was this:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;    

var myTimer = new Timer(1000, 2);
myTimer.addEventListener(TIMER, timerHandler);
myTimer.start();

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent){trace("timerHandler: ");}
```

//but it gives this error:

```
Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert r1.deval.rt::FunctionDef@50ef781 to Function.
```

//also have tried with setInterval with this code:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.setInterval;
function d(){trace("cc");}
setInterval(d, 2000);
```

//but console error says:

```
Error: Call to a possibly undefined method.
```

//probably need to import something. tried tho import "import flash.utils.setInterval;" but gives this error:"Error: You must import the class before being able to instantiate it. Ex. import flash.display.MovieClip;"

Can you help me on This? timer or setInterval functions?
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the error message you're getting, but you do have an error in your code at the point at which you assign the event listener for your timer. You need to access the event name constant from the TimerEvent class like so:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;    

var myTimer = new Timer(1000, 2);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
myTimer.start();

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent){trace("timerHandler: ");}
```

There's a decent explanation here on the [advantages of using the ActionScript 3.0 Timer class over setInterval](http://www.negush.net/blog/how-to-use-timer-class-instead-of-setinterval/).

Comment: it seems that there is no timerEvents, in this console...because the error it gives..

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like there is no way to achieve this. FlashFirebug uses [D.eval](http://www.riaone.com/products/deval/) library and I can't find that it supports timers or intervals right now.

Comment: i have asked o-minds but they doesn't reply.. it only uses D.eval? are you sure?..so it is very limited.. Does this library support callbacks?..i think not because have tried to set a callback in flash to react to a javascript timer and can't get it to work..?...

Comment: The error `Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert r1.deval.rt::FunctionDef@50ef781 to Function.` sais that it's all about D.eval. And yes, I didn't find any way to add event listeners or something like that...

Comment: damnn... very bad...no way to do some kind of automated script to the console..at the beginning i thought that this error was associated to a missing import library, ...do you know any way to automatic print  traces to the javascript console without any timer? ..yeah this can't be done without timers or callback timers.. thanks anyway Art :P

Comment: What do you mean by printing traces? Simple Firebug’s Console Log is not what you are looking for? http://labs.findsubstance.com/2008/02/26/firebugs-console-log-flash-debugging-made-easy/

Comment: firebug console doesn't give me acess to the data embeded in flash page (and properties like html value for example). I use flashfirebug to acess the properties of the elements (it shows the dom tree and in each element all the properties). trace("hello") is equivalent to console.log("hello")... That's the only way i found to get data from flash page, I have tried fidler but it doesn't work, and fidler plus wireshark (mim) but no..So, doing trace(log) of the property i want to firebug (with timer because it changes is value -temperature) was my goal. Just needed the timer to send to firebug

Comment: i' am using externalInterface to send..don't know if you understood?..Temperature data that is embedded in flash, access it in the dom tree of flashfirebug, and send it to firebug..but have to be automated. so the timer should be in the flash console (or a callback to a timer in firebug) but the 2 not working.. stuck in this..probably search for another idea? what you think? thanks for replies

Comment: Any reason you can't push the data embedded in the Flash to Firebug via ExternalInterface rather than the other way round? Do you have access to the source code for the Flash?

Comment: yes i can send the data embedded in flash to firebug using ExternalInterface. I do that, But it have to be automatic. the only way to be automatic is using timers. No, i have not access to source code in flash. The only access is the dom with the elements properties. Probably no solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you've sorted it yet but it looks like:

```
var num:int = setInterval(d, 2000);
```

and if you import import flash.utils.clearInterval; you can stop it like:

```
clearInterval(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
myTimer.addEventListener(TIMER, timerHandler);
```

It should be:

```
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
//              add this ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old. But answering it to help anyone in the future.

[FlashFirebug 4.8.0](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashfirebug/versions/) which is still on the approval queue (at the time of answer) should enable you to inject an SWF file inside the running SWF.

That would allow you to use full AS3 capabilities when you hit limitations with the console.