# How to run Timer on Flash Firebug?

Tags: flash, actionscript, timer, firebug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [flashfirebug As3 console timer or setInterval not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579309/flashfirebug-as3-console-timer-or-setinterval-not-working)

Anyone knows how to run a timer on ActionScript 3.0 console of flashfirebug Pro?

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;    

var myTimer = new Timer(1000, 2);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler); //I have typed wrong not "TIMER"
myTimer.start();

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent){trace("timerHandler: ");}
```

//but it gives this error:

```
Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert r1.deval.rt::FunctionDef@50ef781 to Function.
```

It seems that there is no access to timers in this console.. I have asked o-minds developer but no replies on this. 
Have tried also to callback a timer from firebug but again no callback functions available...
The goal was to do a automatic script on the console (the only way is with a timer).

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
```

Comment: Typed wrong in the post.. have done like that.. I just edited original post

Answer (score 0):

You need a type on your timer declaration and TimerEvent.TIMER for your event name:

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;    

var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 2);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);
myTimer.start();

function timerHandler(event:TimerEvent){trace("timerHandler: ");}
```

I've updated my code with a working solution that I tested.

Comment: Typed wrong in the post..sorry... have changed "TIMER" to "TimerEvent.TIMER".. I just edited original post. Did you tested in flashfirebug console? not working for me...gives that Eval error..